Keypad library isn't working or I am wrong somewhere
I am using PICSimLab to simulate a keypad. The configuration of the keypad is as shown in the picture:

and the code is:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte rows = 4; // 4 rows
const byte columns = 3; // 3 columns
char keys[rows][columns] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
}; // keymap

byte rowPins[rows] = {3, 2, 1, 0};
byte columnPins[columns] = {6, 5, 4}; // set up connection pins

Keypad kp = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, columnPins, rows, columns); // set up keypad

const int d4 = 7, d5 = 8, d6 = 9, d7 = 10, en = 11, rs = 12; // set up LCD pins
LiquidCrystal myLcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7); // set up LCD

void setup() {
  myLcd.begin(16,2);
  myLcd.print("Last name:Smith");
  myLcd.clear();
  myLcd.print("AM:1396");
  myLcd.setCursor(0,1);
  myLcd.print("ENTER VOL:");
}

void insertVol() {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 4) {
    char key = kp.getKey();
    while(key) {
      myLcd.setCursor(i+11,1);
      myLcd.print(key);
    }
    i++;
  }
}

void loop() {
}

The purpose is to display some lines on the LCD, then type in a 4-digit password and display each digit of the password on the LCD crystal.
I get this picture which is correct:

But when I am pressing any button of the keyboard it isn't shown on the screen. I want to comment something else the length of the string "ENTER VOL" is 10 characters so we start at the position 11,1 of the LCD screen when printing out the password.
I have tried connecting L1 -> 0 , L2 -> 1 , L3 -> 2 , L3 -> 3 and C1 -> 4 , C2 -> 5 , C3 -> 6 in case it mattered, but still nothing. Is the library broken or where am I wrong? I had tried using the Keypad before this project and I had run into the same issues. Help appreciated.

how did you solve the problem before?

I didnt in fact it is a obstacle i cant get past so im asking if someone here knows about this.

Your function loop() is empty. Add these two lines to it:
insertVol();
delay(500);

in order to invoke function insertVol()
